# Ios Simulator in Xcode 6 running at 0.0 fps

Tags: ios

I know other people have asked questions about slow ios simulators before. But my problem is not the the simulator is slow. It is that the simulator runs at 0.0 fps (according to the text at the bottom) and I can't test any of my code. I am very confused and any help would be appreciated. Don't have enough reputation to post an image. But at the bottom it says 3 nodes 0.0 fps.

UPDATE
I deleted the following code from my code and it started working like normal again.

```swift
while left {
            var leftMove = SKAction.moveByX(1, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
            person.runAction(leftMove)
        }
        while !left{
            var rightMove = SKAction.moveByX(-1, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
            person.runAction(rightMove)
        }
```

that was taken from my update() method
here is the whole thing...

```swift
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "guyLeft_1.png")
    var left = true

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

        var ground = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height * 0.2))
        ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.1)
        ground.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        self.addChild(ground)

        person.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.2)
        self.addChild(person)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        !left

    }


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        while left {
            var leftMove = SKAction.moveByX(1, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
            person.runAction(leftMove)
        }
        while !left{
            var rightMove = SKAction.moveByX(-1, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
            person.runAction(rightMove)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says 0fps because it is not able to render the scene just once.

Just change it to

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if left {
        var leftMove = SKAction.moveByX(1, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
        person.runAction(leftMove)
    }
    if !left { // or use an if-else construct
        var rightMove = SKAction.moveByX(-1, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
        person.runAction(rightMove)
    }
}
```

There is really not much to explain here - the while just caused an infinite loop. If you have no `break` statements and the `while` body does not alter the evaluated condition `left` the program will be stuck forever inside the while loop.

Additionally:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    left = false // either
    left = !left // or
}
```

The previous code just evaluates !left and ignores the result - effectively does nothing.

Comment: @AnkithUdupa You are welcome, if it answered your question consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark on its left and / or leaving an upvote.